# Need Help to Resolve Concurrent Modification

Tags: java, collections, concurrentmodification

This is my service code which throws concurrent modification:

```
    public List<PriceTierMI> getMutablePriceTiers() {

            if (mutablePriceList == null) {
                mutablePriceList = new ArrayList<PriceTierMI>();
            } else {
                if (mutablePriceList.size() > 0) {
                    Collections.sort(mutablePriceList , tierComparator);
                }
            }
            return new ArrayList<>(mutablePriceList);

        }


        public List<PriceTierII> getImmutablePriceTiers() {
            return new ArrayList<>(getMutablePriceTiers());
    }

    **Exception:** 
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1473)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:186)
    at ItemPriceTierSequence.getMutablePriceTiers(ItemPriceTierSequence.java:196)
    at ItemPriceTierSequence.getImmutablePriceTiers(ItemPriceTierSequence.java:207)
```

With initial debugging, I found out it sorts 2 times unnecessarily. However after removing the sort in getImmutablePriceTiers() I am still getting the concurrent modification exception. I am not sure what is still missing in the code? Any pointers to solve this issue will be helpful.

Comment: what does your `tierComparator` do (can you post the code too) ?

Comment: Does your code get executed in parallel? `sort` is considered a modification. If you're calling `getImmutablePriceTiers` while some other invocation is currently also execution this, you can easily get the the concurrent modification exception. Easy way would be to return a copy of your `mutablePriceList` collection in the first function.

Comment: @tpschmidt - Yes both the methods are invoked from multiple invocation points. I updated the code based on your feedback. However I am not able to reproduce the threading issue. But I am not 100% sure if this code will really work.

Comment: @tpschmidt `sort()` is not a structural modification. The CME is caused by another thread modifying the list during the sort operation.